# how do i exit a for loop in an if else statement? groovy - java

Tags: loops, if-statement, groovy, exit

My code worked fine until I added the `else` block.

```
String getInputSearch = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("city")

for(int i=0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
    if(getInputSearch == loadData()[i][0]) {
        for(int j=0; j< loadData()[i].length; j++) {
            println(loadData()[i][j])
        }
        println("")
    }
    else {
        println( getInputSearch+ "not a valid city");
    }
}
```

If I add a `break` within the `else` block, the loop only works once and if I don't it keeps printing "not a valid city," even if the city is valid until it reaches the the right index in the array. (data is read from a text file btw)
help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you storing in listArray and what is returned by loadData() ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Print "not a valid city" if the entered text is not among the data? Should the loop end after a match has been found and the elements of `loadData()[i]` have been printed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there's a mismatch between what you're trying to achieve and your approach. You're trying to determine whether the city is valid or not, and if so, print out some data. However, what you're doing instead is checking if a *particular row* has a valid city, which leads to your `if` statement being executed for *every iteration*; hence the multiple "not a valid city" results. Your `if` statement is just too early.

Try something like this:

```
/* Grabs all the rows in loadData() with a matching city.
 * Which means that if the list is empty, then the city is invalid.
 */
def cityData = loadData().findAll { it[0] == getInputSearch }

if(cityData) {
    cityData.each { row ->
        row[1].each { column ->
            println column
        }
        println()
    }
} else {
    println "${getInputSearch} not a valid city"
}
```

And if you're feeling fancy, there's a more stream/pipe like approach:

```
loadData()
    .findAll { it[0] == getInputSearch }
    .with {
        /* asBoolean() tries to coerce the List into a boolean.
         * An empty list is False, while a non-empty list is True
         */
        if(!delegate.asBoolean()) println "${getInputSearch} not a valid city"
        delegate // Return the list itself so that if it's not empty the process will continue.
    }.each { row ->
        row[1].each { column ->
            println column
        }

        println()
    }
```